# MongoDB in Docker container runs out of space for journal

Tags: mongodb, virtualbox, docker

I am using Docker for a test environment inside a VirtualBox virtual machine on Windows. Having the MongoDB container run out of disk space would not be a problem if removing and recreating the container fixed the problem, but this is not the case. How can I get this space back? Right now I'm destroying the VirtualBox VM and rebuilding it to recover, but this is long and painful. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: How much space are you giving this vm?

Comment: I am using whatever default Vagrant on Windows is giving me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove unneeded images by first having a look of which images are there with

```
docker ps -a
```

and remove unneeded ones with

```
docker rmi imageid|name
```

Keep in mind though that images depend on each other - you have to find out which are the ones you really want to remove. The good news is that unneeded dependencies are automatically removed.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this the next time it happens - usually about once a week